# Make an installed app to be Home screen

Tags: android, root, android-launcher

I have root access on my device. I've installed any 3rd-party app (I have no access to source code and let's assume that I can not modify APK at all).

I want to make on of its activities to be home screen. If I can recompile the app, I can just add android.intent.category.HOME category and it will work.

But is it possible to add this category without recompilation if I have root access?

Comment: You can install another app to create custom shortcuts that start Intent's into your Activites

Comment: @cricket_007 seems to be a solution, but if I press Home button inside the desired app, it will return to my home screen and then return back.

Comment: What else would you expect it to do? You've started the app from the Home screen